# How to convert a kind of string like '\x1f' into hexadecimal number in python?

Tags: python, string, hex

In python, if I want to convert a string like '\x1f' into a hexadecimal number, how should I do? I know it is an old question, and I have searched and tried many ways, but all of them proved failed, here are two of them:

eval(): this function post an error: 'unexpected EOF while parsing', it seems like it can not recognize characters like '\x1f'.

'\x1f'.decode('hex'): this function post an error: 'Odd-length string' and I do not know how to deal with it.

I guess I have tried all things I can do, could someone give me an hand?

Answer (score 0):

\x may be delimiter so you can encode in hex using

```
a='\\x1f'
a.encode('hex')
```

Comment: I can actually use this way to get a hexadecimal number, but when I use this value, it will become another value. I think I'd better ask a whole question: I have a string, each element is a hexadecimal number like '\x1f', I want to transfer each element into a decimal integer to use as a pixel color value, if I add '\' at the beginning of each element, the value of this element would not be what I want.

Comment: I have tried this way again several minutes ago, and I find that the result of encode is still 'str' instead of integer, which means it is not a hexadecimal number......

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a string with hex characters in it like -

```
hex_string = '\xf7\x14\xf7\xf9B\xab\x18J\xb6\xb6$\xb9-\x9e\xfd\xecg\xef\x9e\xf8\xc4'
```

In my case, `hex_string` with single '\' didn't work so I used '\\'.

You just need to split and individually convert the hex char to decimal-

```
hex_chars = hex_string.split('\\x') # \\ are used otherwise it'll give error
pixels = []
for char in hex_chars:
    if char != '':
        match = re.match('^([\dAaBbCcDdEeFf]+).*', char)
        pixels.append(int(match.groups()[0],16))
print(pixels)
=> [247, 20, 247, 3995, 171, 24, 182, 182, 185, 158, 253, 236, 239, 158, 248, 196]
```

Comment: I guess I have to use python 2.7, I think I have not ask the question clearly, this is my current obstacle I have a string, each element is a hexadecimal number like '\x1f', I want to transfer each element into a decimal integer to use as a pixel color value, if I add '\' at the beginning of each element like you do in this code, the value of this element would not be what I want...

Comment: Can you post the whole string?

Comment: I get it from a raw data of a image, I use 'print' and get it like this(just part of the whole string):\x1f\x1fD\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2D\x1f\x1f\x1f\x1fD\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2\xb2

Comment: So for each `\x1f` like element, you want it to be converted to decimal integer?

Comment: Yes, because I want to use it to get the original image of this string

Comment: Thank you very much !  I make it ! Now I can get the origin image from this string !